# Set ActionBar title text in center

Tags: android, android-actionbar, center

How can I have actionbar text set to the center. I have used below code to set text to center:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center">


  <TextView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:text="Example"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayOptions(ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom, ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_actionbar_centerTitle, null);

ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
       GravityFlags.Center);

var title = ((TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.title));
title.Text = AgliveResource.ContactUs;

ActionBar.SetCustomView(v, p);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This works perfectly when I have hamburger menu to right along with back icon to left. But there are some screens which does not require hamburger menu, at that time the text does not appear correctly at center.

Image 1 with menu:
[image]
Image 2 without menu:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a margin of 56dp to the right if you do not have a hamburger menu

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
android:gravity="center">


  <TextView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:text="Example"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Will it come properly on different screen size?

Comment: yes because the left icon in the toolbar is 56dp in all the devices. You will have to check it once in tablets, I think its 64dp in tablet, you will have to get different values for tablets using dimens folder

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to change textview width `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navBar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/app_color_Brown">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Privacy Policy"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I dont think this will work, she is using back button from toolbar not from the layout

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy Yes but replace toolbar and add this xml code and i hope this working fine.